# Change Product image Color on Radio button in Magento Neoshop Theme

Tags: xml, magento, radio-button, magento-1.9, configurable-product

I want to change product image color on radio button click in Magento.

I have code written in JS and CSS which changes image color in my simple html file. (Please see code below)

I want to implement same on Magento. Please let me know which files should be added/update with my code or any other way.

I tried to addJS and addCSS in code in xml .

I dont know how to call or add this in Magento.

Please also let me know file paths ..

```js
$('input[name="color"]').on('change', function () {
  $('div.imageDiv')
        .removeClass('original sepia gray')
        .addClass($(this).val());
});
```

```css
img {
     display: block;
     width: 50%;
 }
 .original {
  
 }
 .sepia {
     -webkit-filter: sepia(1);
     filter: sepia(1);
 }
 .gray {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
     filter: grayscale(1);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input name="color" type="radio" value="original" checked="">Color<br>
 <input name="color" type="radio" value="gray">Gray<br>
 <input name="color" type="radio" value="sepia">Sepia<br>
 
 <div class="imageDiv original">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png">
 </div>
```